# str_replace() doesn't replace every occiurence

Tags: php, str-replace

I realized that I have some weird issue with str_replace() where it seemingly doesn't replace every occurence of $search with $replace even tho  i have not specified a  $count variable...
My code

```
    echo "head_title_array ".html_entity_decode($head_title_array['title'])."\n\n";
    $Mytitle = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "_", html_entity_decode($head_title_array['title'])));
    echo "Mytitle ".$Mytitle;
```

and the output:

```
      head_title_array Stay & play golf packages

      Mytitle stay_& play_golf_packages
```

Why is that? I would expect $Mytitle to have a value of "**stay_&_play_golf_packages**".
What's going on here?

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: split you code up into individual steps and make sure you're actually passing around what you think you are. right now you're hiding a LOT of stuff under the hood by passing the decode right to the replace.

Comment: if you have value in $head_title_array['title'] = "Stay & play golf packages"; it will work... actually what is the value in " $head_title_array['title'] ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have [unicode spaces](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) in your string.

Possible solution for you is to use `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace('/\p{Zs}/u', '_', $your_string);
```

[Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Comment: Yep, Thank you! That did it! But can you explain please. I'm not very handy using reg exp and am wondering what \p, {Zs} and /u stand for...? Thanks!

Comment: @cerr `/u` is for unicode, and as you can find on the link in my answer `\p{Zs}` means any white space. So it can be translated as `any whitespace in unicode string`

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't spaces. Try replacing `&nbsp;` and 0xA0.